# Rescind close vote

Tags: support, specific-question, flagging

I put an incorrect close-as-dupe vote on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/100-gunmen-in-a-circle-kill-next-person), which is preventing the OP from offering a bounty. How might I remove this vote to allow the bounty to be placed? I've checked in the `flag` menu (the same menu used to close vote) but I see no option there or elsewhere to rescind.

Comment: I have cleared your flag just now in the review queue.

Comment: @Jamal: Thank you!‎‎‎‎‎

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flags cannot be rescinded.  Only close votes can.  You'll just have to wait until the flag gets cleared in some way, which is after the post is [reviewed in the close queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/close/35595).

Comment: I see, thanks.‎‎